# React:- It's not rendering my HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to make simple HTML form with input type radio and submit button, but don't know why it's not rendering my HTML even not showing any error on console as well.

here is jsfiddle for it :    [`JsFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/rajjuneja49/0wrpyyvq/)

Comment: Please check "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask )". Please include all relevant information in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React render method must have only one parent element your are trying to load multiple parent method check this code [Check here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MrMRz4QLYE0O0WZqMUM9?p=preview)

your RadioOptionGroup should be like

```
 var RadioOptionGroup = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
      {this.props.options.map(function(option){
        return(
        <RadioOption value={option.value}>{option.label}</RadioOption>
      );
  })}
  </div>
      );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

React component **must have** only one root element, now in `RadioOptionGroup` you are trying return several elements.,

```
var RadioOptionGroup = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var options = this.props.options.map(function(option, index) {
      return <RadioOption
                key={ index }
                value={ option.value }>{option.label}</RadioOption>;
    });

    return <div>{ options }</div>;
  }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/26224/)

Comment: @Ravi Juneja could you give feedback?

Comment: @Ravi Juneja have you seen example?